# IIS Express continues running after Visual Studio 2015 debugging session ends

Tags: visual-studio-2015, iis-express, visual-studio-debugging

I've found a problem with Visual Studio 2015, IIS Express, and Update 1 for VS2015. I can perform my debugging session without problems, but when I stop the debugging session, IIS Express remains running. I want IIS Express to stop running when I stop the debugging session.

How I can do it?

Comment: I have come across this same problem after installing Update 1 as well and have not been able to correct it. I've tried enabling and disabling the "Enable Edit and Continue" option, but it did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Uninstalling VS2015 with Update 1, and reinstalling VS2015 without Update 1 was the only way I could resolve this issue on my machine. I too have reported the issue to MS, hopeful they can resolve the issue in the next update.

Comment: Just an FYI, resinstalling VS2015 without Update 1 has caused other issues with my VM now. After I terminate a debugging session and try to edit a file, VS2015 crashes. I'm going to have to setup my VM all over again as I didn't create a snapshot of it prior to upgrading to Update 1 as I should have.

Comment: Hi Anil, thanks for your help. For now I'm working with VS2015 update 1; I have opened a bug, like you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IIS Express closes when I stop debugging (after install VS 2015 update 2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36353293/iis-express-closes-when-i-stop-debugging-after-install-vs-2015-update-2)

Answer (score 0):

Try making sure that "Edit and Continue" is enabled.

Right click on your project and go to properties. Click on the Web section, then under debuggers make sure "Enable Edit and Continue" is checked.

IIS Express is supposed to stop automatically if this debugger is enabled.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/07/11/enable-edit-and-continue-debugging-option-is-now-on-by-default-for-new-web-applications-in-vs2013-preview.aspx

Comment: Hi Snoopyowns, thanks for answer, but there isn't this option in web session on Visual studio 2015.

Comment: It is in the properties of the web application project. The same place where you set the project to use IIS Express or IIS and the url. There is a section called "Debuggers". It should look just like the screenshot in the link I provided.

Comment: On my vs 2015 enterprise there isn't this options. At home, where I have vs 2015 community edition this option is visible! What is the trouble?

Comment: That is strange. I use VS2015 enterprise as well and I can see it on my Web applications. I don't really have a good answer for you then. Although you can check Tools > Options > Debugging, make sure "Enable Edit and Continue" is checked. My settings also have "Apply changes on contine (Native only)", "Warn about stale code (Native only)", "Allow precompiling (Native only)" set as well.

Comment: Thanks snoopyowns for you answer. I don't know because I don't have this option on my Vs on working pc. t is a real mystery.

Comment: No, I haven't installed Update 1 yet.

Comment: Ok I have verified: the problem is update 1 of vs2015; On my home pc I don't have this update and I can see the option, on my work pc I can't see it.

Comment: Honestly, that sounds like a bug to me. It would probably be good to submit to MS. I guess I'll have to stay away from Update 1.

Comment: Yesterday I have submit bug ti MS, and the answer is this: "This setting still exists, but has been moved to Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General
Scroll to the very bottom of the list on the right, and you will find “Enable Edit and Continue”
Sorry for the inconvenience.  More Edit and Continue options became available in VS, so the setting was consolidated." Now I've submitted the problem of IIS Express don't shut down when I close a debug session.

Comment: This didnt work for me so I just stop the site in IIS Express.