# After installing VS 2015 Update 2, IIS Express closes when I stop debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2015

This problem occurs despite unchecked 'Enable Edit & Continue`:

[image: enable edit and continue unchecked]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting this too, extremely frustrating.

Previously once my mvc website had started debugging, I could stop debugging and continue using the site.

If I made a C# code change I'd hit rebuild, and the change would be on the localhost website once I hit refresh.

Basically my work pattern was:
Do some changes, rebuild, give localhost website a quick test to see if change functions as expected

After Update 2, regardless if Enable Edit & Continue is on or off, the website won't be available unless I'm in debug mode

Comment: Same here :/ It really breaks my working pattern.

Comment: I tried fix it by 'repair installation' Visual Studio, did not help

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Disabling "Edit and Continue" did not help.

Comment: I had the same issue.
Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14384964/1611383

Comment: I've [submitted a bug report to Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2562576/edit-continue-cant-be-disabled-which-causes-iis-express-to-stop-when-the-debugger-is-stopped). Please upvote it!

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky link not working

Comment: @sohaiby It is for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been resolved in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.  Read the [**release notes**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs) here.

***Web Developer Tools***

> *For ASP.NET Web Application projects, when "Enable Edit and Continue" checkbox is unchecked, the IIS Express process will no longer stop
>   every time you stop debugging.*

Answer (score 11):

This work-around is working for me. Instead of hitting the "Stop" debugging button, go to the Debug menu item and select "Detach All". This will detach VS from IIS Express, but leave it up and running.

Comment: I've had to use the same work-around since installing Update 2.  Really really annoying.

Comment: Works for me. I've added the "Detach all" button to the Debug toolbar for easier use (until a solution or clarification is provided by Microsoft)

Comment: It's really annoying

Comment: When I do this then recompile, reload in browser, it never reloads.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `Debug -> Detach All` button instead.
How to add "Detach All" button inside of "Stop":

1-
[image: add "Detach All" button inside of "Stop"]
2-
[image: add "Detach All" button inside of "Stop"]
3-
[image: add "Detach All" button inside of "Stop"]
4-
[image: add "Detach All" button inside of "Stop"]

**Update:**
In Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 you have `Enable Edit & Continue` in project's properties again.