# VS2015 Update 2 - Stops IISExpress With Edit & Continue Disabled

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I just installed Update 2 into VS2015 (pro edition). Now, when I stop the project, IISExpress is automatically stopped. This was not happening before the update. Has anyone else experienced this? And more importantly, is there a better fix than doing Browse With?

Also, I've had Edit & Continue disabled forever; that is not the problem.

Comment: I was *just* about to post this same question because I'm experiencing the same thing. I think it's a bug. That being said, for the time being, I've used [this workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14384964) - using `Detach All` rather than `Stop`. What's also weird is that it seems `Edit & Continue` still works even though I have it disabled.

Comment: Thanks @TheCloudlessSky, that did it. Especially once I changed Shift+F5 to Detach All. However, I do hope they fix this soon.

Comment: I've [submitted a bug report to Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2562576/edit-continue-cant-be-disabled-which-causes-iis-express-to-stop-when-the-debugger-is-stopped), please upvote it!

Comment: I've upvoted! How annoying!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IIS Express closes when I stop debugging (after install VS 2015 update 2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36353293/iis-express-closes-when-i-stop-debugging-after-install-vs-2015-update-2)

Comment: I can't even find the Edit & Continue setting in the project properties anymore.  I have it disabled at the IDE-level and it still stops IIS.  Very, very annoying.  Thanks @TheCloudlessSky, bug report upvoted.

Comment: VS2015 Update 3 is supposed to have fixed this. https://www.visualstudio.com/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs#knownissues

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that this have been fixed in Update 3

Comment: @Grinn Do not forget to uncheck "Edit & Continue" in Application property page -> Web -> Debugger

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue, and while this is not a fix, it is another work around.

If you have more than one web project in the solution, set one of the other ones as the startup project.  After Update 2, when debugging, IIS Express is starting all (I tried a solution with 2, so at least in that case it was both) regardless of which one is the startup project.  VS will only launch the startup project, but if you look at the Applications list in IIS Express it will show all of them.  If you stop debugging, the startup project will stop, but the other(s) will still be running.

So in my case, with two web projects, I set the *other* one as the startup project, and I'm able to continue working as I had before the update.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've only got one project in my web solution so this approach won't work for me. Thanks.